# Trying to open ports via Windows Firewall, but only when process is running (Error: "Syntaxerror")

Tags: windows, batch-file, firewall

I want to make a little Batch script for me which shall help me keep tracking and spying on my computer as limited as possible. I use TinyWall as my primary firewall, as it's really light and simple. Through it's "Show connections" ability, I came to the idea that I could stop persistently allowing specific ports/programs and only open them when I really need it.

So I wrote (with a lot of research) a Batch script that will add Firewall exceptions (which open several ports), open the specific program. After that I used an if-Statement to constantly (while the batch script is running) lookup in tasklist if the process of the program is running. If not, it shall delete the Firewall exceptions and close the program.

When I run the script (with "cmd.exe /k"), the program opens, but it seems like the exceptions didn't apply, since the program reports no Internet connection. Also the cmd window closes immediately (without "cmd.exe /k") after the program opened. I don't want this to happen.

What also seems strange to me is that (with the /k parameter for cmd) I only get the response "Syntax error." (translated from my language, don't know what it originally reports) without any further information.

I need to run the script within an administrative cmd window. Is there a way to exploit that? It worked before I used the "advfirewall" (advanced Firewall, I guess) command, but the help of some command manual told me that the plain "firewall" command is outdated and I should use "advfirewall firewall" instead.

Does someone know how I accomplish my goal? I would be really grateful.

PS: Sorry for the long text.

TLDR: My script doesn't work. If you want to help me, please look trough the code.

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL
echo Adding Firewall Exceptions for Origin ...
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OriginIn port 3216" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=3216 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OriginOut port 3216" dir=out protocol=TCP localport=3216 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OriginIn port 49218" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=49218 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OriginOut port 49218" dir=out protocol=TCP localport=49218 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OriginIn port 49819" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=49819 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="OriginOut port 49819" dir=out protocol=TCP localport=49819 action=allow
timeout 2
echo Done. Starting Origin. Have fun gaming!
start "Origin" /DE:\Origin\ Origin.exe
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Origin.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Origin.exe">NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0
(
    netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name "OriginIn port 3216"
    netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name "OriginOut port 3216"
    netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name "OriginIn port 49218"
    netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name "OriginOut port 49218"
    netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name "OriginIn port 49819"
    netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name "OriginOut port 49819"
)
echo Deleting Firewall Exceptions (Reason: Origin isn't running anymore) ...
timeout 5
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start "Origin" /DE:\Origin\ Origin.exe
```

Guess only: The help for `start` indicates that there should be a SPACE between the `D` and the `E`.